# Testing for MySQL errors

Tags: mysql, sql, testing, expected-exception

Whenever MySql encounters an error, it stops processing, even if there are more statements following.  I need it to report errors but continue processing the remaining statements.  I read in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqltest/2.0/en/writing-tests-expecting-errors.html that you can use --error but MySql just says I have a syntax error.

For example, this stored procedure which adds a name to a unique column should cause a 1062 error...

```
...
call AddName('Joe');
--error 1062
call AddName('Joe');
...
```

...but MySql just points out the line number and says syntax error near '--error 1062 call AddName('Joe');'

It's also worth noting that comments starting with "--" don't seem to register as comments.  I imagine that might be related.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use something intended for the test framework, as explained here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqltest/2.0/en/writing-tests-expecting-errors.html

Comment: Right you are! I saw that article and it didn't even cross my mind that such thing might exist.  Thanks.